# Analyze/filter string input by character in masm32

Tags: assembly, masm32

I am attempting to get values from a user for a word (size) array, but only accept values that would not be too large and are numeric (0-9, -32768 to 32767). I'm fairly new to masm, so I googled a bit and thought I understood a way to examine each char, but it's not working out.  What I have so far is this:

```
.data
...
strInput    byte    7 dup(?)            ;used to store user input
                                        ;6 available chars + null
.code
...
userInput:
    ...code that converts strInput ascii to int and puts it in eax...
    cmp eax, 32767       ;compare input to max positive word size
    jg exceedsBounds     ;jump to error message
    cmp eax, -32768      ;compare input to max negative word size
    jl exceedsBounds     ;jump to error message 
    mov iVal, eax        ;store value in signed placeholder
    mov esi, 0           ;use esi as a counter, set it to 0
    jmp checkChars       ;go to inspect chars

checkChars:
     mov al, strInput[esi]  ;grab the byte at esi
                   ;input method stores each char as a byte capped by null
     inc esi                ;move to next byte
     cmp al, 0              ;check if at the end (null cap)
     jmp goodEntry          ;if at end, it's good
     cmp al, 45             ;compare to minus sign
     je minus               ;jump to minus handler (checks for multiples)
     cmp al, 57             ;compare to "9"
     jg invalidChar         ;if al is greater than ascii 57, invalid
     cmp al, 49             ;compare to "0"
     jl invalidChar         ;if al is less than ascii 49, invalid
     jmp checkChars         ;loop back to check next char
```

In my head, strInput is ascii, so if I compare to the table value it should work, but none of the checkChars jumps are working.  Any clues as to what I am misunderstanding here?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. If you already converted it to a number, why are you checking the digits later? Also, is your conversion code working? Anyway, `jmp goodEntry` is unconditional you probably wanted `je goodEntry`. PS: ascii code of `0` is `48` not `49`. You might want to use character constants ;)

Comment: THANK YOU.  Yes, the unconditional jump was the problem, in my head I was reading that as je.  Also thanks for the tip on 0.  Noob question but what do you mean by character constraints?

Comment: Not "constraints", constants. E.g. you can just write `'0'` in most assemblers, although I am not sure about masm.

Comment: Ah ok.  Sorry, looking at a screen for 7 hours straight has apparently killed my reading comprehension.  Using 'char' does seem to work, so that simplifies things in the future.  Thanks again!

Comment: The initial test for 16bit range can be simplified to single compare: `movsx esi,ax` `cmp esi, eax` `jne exceedsBounds` ... not sure whether that's more performant, or more readable, I just had idea about testing unsigned value `cmp eax,0xFFFF` `jna exceeds...` first, then I realized that would not work for negative 32b values like -1, and then I wondered whether there is single test for it any way, ended with the `movsx` variant (16b part converted to 32b must be equal to original 32b, if it is within 16b range).

Comment: Thinking about it further (still feeling angry by fooling myself by that `cmp 0xFFFF`), the important part is, that upper 16b are either zeroes, or ones, and they are equal to the 16th bit of bottom 16b. ... ahh... and finally I realized how that single test with `FFFF` can be done: `add eax,0x8000` `cmp eax,0xFFFF` `ja exceedsBounds` `sub eax,0x8000` .. ok, I knew there is some way, but forgot the exact code.